# What kind of SSD formats do Raspberry Pis support?

Tags: linux, ssd, raspberry-pi, bitcoin, bitcoind

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi model B+ to Run a Bitcoin Lightning node so I was learning how to use it and stuff like that.

Before anything I have to download and sync the bitcoin core software so I was planning to do all that first on my iMac on an old SSD I have.

So the questions are:

- What kind of formats do Raspberry Pis support?
- What kind of format do you suggest me to use in order to later connect that SSD to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: http://www.simplyembedded.org/archives/filesystems-with-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Welcome abaord. You probably ought to have asked this on our sister site https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian for Raspberry Pi is Linux based, so I would recommend ext4. If you would like to use the drive on other operating systems and not Linux exclusively, try FAT.

Also, [this website](https://www.howtogeek.com/73178/what-file-system-should-i-use-for-my-usb-drive/) has a really good table that compares some file systems.

Comment: Good answer (+1), although realistically, one tends to download an image such as [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and decompress it, so that the file system is already chosen.